# mod rewrite add url param

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm working on an integration with Yiiframework and Joomla.  I have it working for the most part, but want to make it a little cleaner.  The URL that is called in Joomla needs to get some URL Parameters appended to the URL.  I have setup the .htaccess to rewrite the URL, but it's not working and I can't figure out why.  Please help.

What the URL current is:

```
/index.php?r=site/index
```

What I want it to append is "option=com_jumi&fileid=3" so it looks like this

```
/index.php?r=site/index&option=com_jumi&fileid=3
```

Here is what I have for the rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^r=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/index.php$ /index.php?r=%1&option=com_jumi&fileid=3 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Looking for some guidance, thanks

Comment: Think I got it working properly with this
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)r=(.*) [NC]`
`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(.*)r=(.*)&option=com_jumi&fileid=3 [NC]`
`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?r=%2&option=com_jumi&fileid=3 [NC,L,R=301]`